# Show Copy dialog by default

Tags: unity, files, unity-2d, transfer

In Unity, when i move files, I see this:

[image]

icon that tells me there is a transfer going on. I would rather see the window with multiple progress bars that tells me what the disk write speed is, and the amount of progress on each. Is there a way to enable, and make that behaviour the default?

I see that I can right click, and select "show copy dialog", I would rather see it by default.

I am using Ubuntu 14.04.2 LTS

Comment: Im suprised no one showed up saying dude, just use mate. which is what I ended up doing.